# Fingerprint login in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, fingerprint-reader

How can I use fingerprint reader to login in ubuntu 20.04?
My laptop is Asus Vivobook S14.
Ram memory: 8Gb
processor: Intel i5 8th gen

Answer (score 1):

This is because the fingerprint sensor on the Asus notebooks is not yet supported in the libfprint library. (It's the Elan Microelectronics reader)

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/1641290 and please add your vote by clicking the "yes, it affects me too" indicator at the top of the bug report. The more people show that they are affected, the greater the chance that this gets assigned to somebody to fix.

Because the hardware is not known, it doesn't even show in the lshw listing.